# HTML to open url based on text box entry

Tags: html, forms

I know only basic HTML

I want to put a text box on my website in which if a user enters his order number, it will open the link to that order summary.

The links to those order summary are saved on my web server in the format of ORDERNUMBER-DATE (example: http://www.mywebsite.com/orders/OD12354-22.02.14.html)

All I want is 2 text boxes where the user enters order number and a date.
on clicking submit, it should take the user to the link automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it in PHP. You would of course need to validate that the user has entered the data in the correct formats, but that is another chapter.

> findorder.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['order']) && !empty($_POST['date'])) {

    $redirect = "orders/" . $_POST['order'] . "-" . $_POST['date'] . ".html";

    if(file_exists($redirect) == true) {
        header('Location: ' . $redirect);
        die();
    }
    else {
        echo "Order not found";
    }

}
?>

<form action="findorder.php" method="POST">
    <input id="order" name="order" type="text" placeholder="Order number">
    <input id="date" name="date" type="date" placeholder="Date">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Update: I added the file_exists bit. Note that you can't pass a proper URL there, just a filepath.

Comment: can you tell me how to manage a redirect in this?
for example if the order is not found, it should redirect to a particular page?

Comment: This script will create a redirect, but as you probably noticed it will also redirect to non-existing pages/orders. There are several ways of doing this, but the best way would be if you could get access to and understand the underlying database which contain the orders. Then you can use a SQL query to check.

Comment: I'm not using a database for these html files. What I'm trying to say is that when i put a wrong entry,it redirects automatically to a website. I want the code to see if on submission it is redirecting to a particular website, if yes then redirect to a link provided by me. How is that possible? The code should internally check all this before redirecting only then do a redirect

Comment: if the script and your static order files are on the same system, you could simply try PHP's `file_exists()`.

Comment: Sorry for asking the question again twice.  How do use that file_exists in the code provided by you?

Comment: `if(file_exists($url) == true) {
     echo "found";
 }
 else {
     echo "not found";
 }` Note that this won't work on remote urls, only within the same file system.

Comment: Yes of course. I updated my answer. Please do some testing and try to understand the limitations of `file_exists`.

Comment: this code doesnt lead to the file? the previous code had a link to my file right? in this code evn on entering correct it says order not found?

Comment: Well, then something obviously went wrong. Try changing the $redirect variable so it makes the correct filepath. I can't know the relative paths of your site. I'm not a wizard, sadly.

Comment: Got everything to work perfectly. Could you just tell me how to validate if data is entered in correct format?

Comment: Validating the input should be a new stack overflow question. You could make it easy for yourself and just write some instructions to the user above the form.

Answer (score 0):

HTML alone would not suffice for this. The best option would be to use Javascript (likely jQuery) to grab the contents of the text boxes, and then when a submit button is pressed, have the browser redirect to your static path plus your dynamic order information. An example of you HTML might be as follows:

```
<form>
    <input id="order" name="order" type="text" required>
    <input id="date" name="date" type="date" required>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You'd then use jQuery to pull the input contents on submit:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var order = $('#order').val();
  var date = $('#date').val();

  // Format date and order input as necessary

  // Construct URL path and redirect here
  window.location('http://www.mywebsite.com/orders/' + order + '-' + date + '.html');
});
```

Obviously, you'd need to validate and ensure the input is safe before performing the redirect. Have a read up on [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [`window.location()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)

Comment: How do I input the jquery?
im a newbie!

how can i put this jquery part in this html?

Comment: @yash. You're going to have to learn a bit of Javascript first. I'd suggest googling the HTML `<script>` tag. Once you've written the Javascript code, you should embed it within the script tag on your HTML page.

Comment: So this j query should come in the script tag in the webpage?

Comment: @yash. Yes, the Javascript (don't confuse it with jQuery) is embedded within the script tag. Obviously my code isn't complete though. You'll need to create your own specific implementation.